# Grouping together of lines while doing line segmentation of printed text

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation, text-extraction

I have been trying to segment lines from a printed text document. I have followed the following paper:

A Hough Transform based Technique for Text Segmentation Satadal Saha, Subhadip Basu, Mita Nasipuri and Dipak Kr. Basu

As per the paper, I used Hough transform to generate straight lines over the text and restricting angles in the vicinity of 90 degrees and connected component algorithm to group the generated straight lines to separate out lines from the text.

The hough transform output is given below:

[image: Hough transform output]

But, the straight lines generated sometimes overlap between two text lines and more than one line segment gets grouped together.

The bounding boxes of lines in the text is given below:

[image: bounding box image of line segments of text]

Can anybody please help me to avoid this grouping together of lines of text? Please suggest a method so that the connected component analysis treat the lines of text as separate components.

Comment: A quick advice is to apply an `Erode` operation in the image obtained by Hough. Kernel should be like 1x3 (i.e. longer height wise) to make some gap between two lines. This will help making some gap and thus will avoid overlapping.

Comment: I believe that an opening morphology may be cleaner than just an erode as it will try harder to preserve your actual dimensions (where erode will result in 2 pixel undersized boxes).

Comment: @SneakyPolarBear I tried your suggestion. I am getting better results. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using connected components to group your hough-lines into text-lines. This process is *very* sensitive to noise: even one misdetected pixel can bring together two lines.
You can make this process more robust if you look at the average "on" pixels per line in the image:

```
bw = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/tg2xN.png');
bw=bw>100;
figure; plot( mean(bw,2) ); xlabel('image row'); ylabel('#"on" pixels');
```

[image]

The red line shows 7.5% threshold on number of "on" pixels per row. As you can see it can help distinguish between well connected hough-lines to falsely connected ones.
Use this threshold to amend the mask:

```
msk = bsxfun(@times, bw, mean(bw,2)>0.075);
```

Now you can get the proper bounding boxes

```
bb=regionprops(bwlabel(msk,8),'BoundingBox');
```

Resulting with:

[image]

Comment: This method (although strong) has a key flaw in that it is assuming full line length.  I mean to say that a very short line of text at the end of the paragraph will generate false trips
There would be a much wider set of successful threshold values if you normalized to line length somehow.
A way I could see this being done is if you run a windowed average pixel down the document.  Basically what is the average on pixel on each line (and window that over several lines).  You could use this term to normalize and therefore I think greatly expand your target zone

Comment: @SneakyPolarBear you are absolutely right. I wanted to keep this answer as clear as possible and I refrained from such modifications. However, based on the nature of this input, you can do a much simpler thing: all the short lines are short in the same way: they all start at the left side of the page. You can do a column-sum and see where you get maximal "row support" and compute the mask according to these columns only.